# How to convert DAE to PNG programmatically without rendering?

Tags: java, c++

At present I am rendering a DAE using a c++ based graphics engine, and programmatically taking a screenshot to get the PNG image as if the camera is viewing from above (looking directly down). This is quite tedious.

Since I do not need to actually look at the models on screen, is it possible to do the same programmatically without rendering using java ?

At present, it is easy to convert between other 2d formats such as PNG to jpeg using buffered image:

```
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage( pngImage.getWidth(), pngImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
newImage.createGraphics().drawImage( pngImage, 0, 0, Color.BLACK, null);
```

Is there a similar way to load the DAE and take the equivalent of a screenshot by specifying the camera position, angle and distance as input coordinates ?

Comment: DAE could probably be rendered off-screen, but then it's still rendered, and it still needs that graphics engine. Does that satisfy your requirement? There cannot be any simple conversion such as between two different raster graphics formats, DAE is not a raster graphic format.

Comment: @harold sure - that could work. What do you have in mind ? Perhaps your solution is much faster than my current approach.

Comment: Modify the graphics engine slightly so that it renders to a texture rather than to the screen, ie an FBO in OpenGL or RenderTarget in DirectX

Comment: @harold editing the c++ engine is not the issue, its just that its very slow since it loads an enormous amount of stuff which can't be avoided. Hence was looking at an alternative. For example in three.js it is a few lines of code to get a 2d projection, but that is javascript...